# ScrollViewの中にListViewを入れた時に、ListViewの更新時に最下部までスクロールしてしまう

Tags: android

ScrollViewをRootとしたActivityにViewPagerを使用し、
以下のような、Topのカバー画像 + 横スクロールできるページをつくろうとしております。

ページ部分のFragmentは、ListViewでつくられており、コンテンツをリスト形式で表示するようにしているのですが、ListViewにてnotifyDataSetChange()を呼んだときに画面全体が最下部までスクロールされてしまいます。
また、ViewPagerのsetCurrentItem()を呼んだ際も同様に最下部までスクロールしてしまいます。

本事象について、有効な手段をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。

```
 -----------------
 | toolbar       |
 -----------------
 | Cover         |
 |               |
 |               |
 -----------------
 | tab           |
 -----------------
 | Fragment *4   |
 |               |
 |               |
 -----------------
```

■ Activityのlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="640dp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

■ Fragmentのlayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height=“640dp">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=“640dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/no_match_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: ActivityにScrollViewを含める意図が良く分かりません、Fragmentの中にListViewがあるなら縦スクロールできるので必要なさそうな気がしますがどうでしょう。

Comment: 画面スクロール時に、カバー部分も一緒にスクロールしたいという理由から、ScrollViewをRootにしていました。

Answer (score 1):

ScrollViewの中身がLinerLayoutに入っていないのが謎です。
LinerLayoutに入れれば解決しそうですが・・・。

あとtabとFragmentを表示するためのViewがないのは省略しているからでしょうか？